# How to refer to executable inside anaconda environment in Snakemake

Tags: python, conda, pipeline, snakemake

I'm using `vcf2maf` to annotate variants as part of a `snakemake` pipeline

```
rule vcf2maf:
    input:
        vcf="vcfs/{sample}.vcf",
        fasta=vep_fasta,
        vep_dir=vep_dir
    output:
        "mafs/{sample}.maf"
    conda:
        "../envs/annotation.yml"
    shell:
        """
        vcf2maf.pl --input-vcf {input.vcf} --output-maf {output} \
            --tumor-id {wildcards.sample}.tumor \
            --normal-id {wildcards.sample}.normal \
            --ref-fasta {input.fasta} --filter-vcf 0 \
            --vep-data {input.vep_dir} --vep-path [need path]

        """
```

The `conda` environment has two packages: `vcf2maf` and `vep`. `vcf2maf` requires a path to `vep` to run properly, but I'm not sure how to access `vep`'s path since it's stored inside the `conda` environment which will have a user specific absolute path. Is there an easy way to get `vep`'s path so I can refer to it for `--vep-path`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the unix `which` command like:

```
veppath=`which vep`
vcf2maf.pl --vep-path $veppath ...
```

> [vep path is] stored inside the conda environment which will have a user specific absolute path

The variable `CONDA_PREFIX` contains the path to the current conda environment. so you could also do something like:

```
vcf2maf.pl --vep-path $CONDA_PREFIX/bin/vep ...
```